# BSONDocument to byte array

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo

I'm trying to post BSONDocument read from mongo to AWS Kinesis stream. However Kinesis API needs message as Byte array. Is there any way to covert BSONDocument(specifically reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument) to byte array?

Comment: **EDIT** reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument object has write method that writes to different types of buffer.                                                         

val buffer = new ArrayBSONBuffer()
BSONDocument.write(doc, buffer)
val data = buffer.array

Answer (score 0):

```
 MongoClient m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
 var db = m.GetDatabase("TestDatabase");

 var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("SomeCollection");

 // this will contain binary data (0s and 1s)
 var binaryData = collection.Find("{SomeProperty:true}").ToBson();
```

Hopefully this works I am not sure.